# Is it possible to read XRay activities via REST?

Tags: rest, jira, jira-xray

I have this report of a test execution for a test from a test plan: https://myjira/secure/XrayExecuteTest!default.jspa?testExecIssueKey=XXX&testIssueKey=XXX&testPlanIssueKey=XXX

and there is a box called "Activity" where I can see all the changes made to the status of the test execution. Is there any REST call to retrieve this data?

For example something like "xxx changed status from blocked to executing."

Unfortunately, I do not see any of this data in the standard JIRA issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, as of July 2023, the activity information is not exportable through the [REST API](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/REST+API). You can request an improvement to support that, by [reaching out to Xray support team](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2).

It's possible to export that information using the built-in [Document Generator](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Exporting+a+Test+Execution#ExportingaTestExecution-ExportingTestRunActivity) feature though, to a Word document for example.

Note: there is a non-public endpoint that provides that information:
https://yourjiraserver/rest/raven/1.0/testrun/8520/activity?limit=10
However, usage of private endpoints is non-recommended in production. They may be changed at any moment, they are not documented, and support won't be able to assist on them. So please have this in mind.